# How to remove the first two characters in a varbinary string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove the first two characters in the select statement. The data that I only need is

```
10160000
1016FFFF
```

This is the query to fetch the data that I've done

```
SELECT TOP(1) CONVERT(varchar(10), Start_Rg, 1) AS Start_Rg
    , CONVERT(varchar(10), End_Rg, 1) AS End_Rg
FROM Range
```

But the data that has been displayed is `0x10160000` and `0x1016FFFF`. How can I use `TRIM` function with the convert function? Is it possible?

This is my code using `SUBSTRING`. But it removes the 0000 and FFFF. What I need is to remove the 0x only

```
SELECT TOP(1) SUBSTRING(Start_Rg, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(End_Rg, 1, 2)
FROM Range WHERE status = 'New'
```

Comment: I've tried substring. But it removes the 0000 and FFFF. What I need is to remove the 0x only.

Comment: Yes. The datatype for the values are `varbinary`. I've updated the code for substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`convert` style 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles).

```
SELECT TOP(1) CONVERT(varchar(10), Start_Rg, 2) AS Start_Rg
    , CONVERT(varchar(10), End_Rg, 2) AS End_Rg
FROM [Range];
```

And FYI so you can use `substring` in the future, the first number is the starting index, so in your case it should be 3, not 1. And you have to apply the `substring` function to a **string**, so the `convert` is still required.

```
SELECT TOP(1) SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10), Start_Rg, 1), 3, 8) AS Start_Rg
    , SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10), End_Rg, 1), 3, 8) AS End_Rg
FROM [Range];
```